# javascript for statement and operator in

Tags: ecmascript-6

There is a note in ecma-262 Specification:

> The [In] grammar parameter is needed to avoid confusing the in operator in a relational expression with the  in operator in a for statement.

so are there any ways to make

```
for (let i in x in y) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

print something ?

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses will make it parse more clearly:

```js
for (let i in (x in y)) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

But it actually parses fine without them. The disambiguation is needed for the other kind of for loop:

```js
for (let a = b in c; false;); // does not parse

for (let a = (b in c); false;); // parses fine
```

The reason your snippet isn't printing anything is that `x in y` always results in a boolean, so it's not going to print anything unless you've defined enumerable properties on `Boolean.prototype` or `Object.prototype`:

```js
Boolean.prototype.foo = 'bar';
for (let a in ('' in {})) {
   console.log(a);
} // prints 'foo'
```